# Need equivalent of JSP tag in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsp, tags

```
public class RadioOptions{

          private String key;
          private String value;
          //getter and setter methods
       }
```

Here you can retrieve the calls using the key value:

```
List<RadioOptions> radioOption= new ArrayList<RadioOptions>();
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("1", "This is option 1.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("2", "This is option 2.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("3", "This is option 3.") );
        radioOption.add( new RadioOptions("4", "This is option 4.") );
```

What will be react equivalent tag of this JSP Tag:

```
 <s:radio label="Please select the best choice" name="answer" list="radioOption" 
 listKey="key" listValue="value" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTML <input type="radio">`  to select only one of a limited number of choices  . the same way your JSP Tag `<s:radio/>` works  .

Example :

```
<label>
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="answer"
    value="1"
    
  />
  Please select the best choice
</label>
```

You can find more information on [how to use radio buttons in React](http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-react-16/)